# Grep Pattern From TAR Output

Tags: linux, bash, grep, tar, restore

**===UPDATE===**

@Cyrus answer was the one that worked, but, this led to another issue that's related that I missed.

There are some folders with folders within folders, so `httpdocs/<folder1>/<folder2>/<etc>/index.php` and so the '*' is picking them up too.

Really all I want is to match the pattern `httpdocs/<folder>/index.php`

I'm rubbish with RegEx so unsure of what I could put. Any ideas?

---

I have a 25GB `tar.gz` file, and from this I want to extract certain files. The file location is:

`httpdocs/<account>/index.php`

The `<account>` just means that it's just a name - not overly important.

There's around 70+ of these `index.php` files in this exact format, and I need to extract only them files from the TAR.

I can do it per individual file, like so (`tar -xf site_support_server.com_user-data_1509221232.tgz httpdocs/hotel/index.php`) but as I say their's around 70 of these and I don't want to go through it 1 by 1.

I thought maybe `tar -xf site_support_server.com_user-data_1509221232.tgz httpdocs/*/index.php` would work, but I don't think it recognizes the '*' as a wildcard.

Am I missing something or does anybody else have any suggestions on how to quickly do this?

Many thanks!

Comment: If your file is a gzip compressed tar file (.tgz or .tar.gz) add option `-z`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU tar:

```
tar -xvzf your_file.tgz --wildcards "*/index.php"
```

**Update**

```
tar -tvzf your_file.tgz --wildcards "httpdocs/*/index.php" --exclude="httpdocs/*/*/index.php"
```

Comment: This worked, so thank you for that, but it led to another issue with the RegEx. I've updated my question.

Comment: Thanks @Cyrus! This is exactly what I need :)

Comment: Is the `---wildcards` flag unique to the `tar` command? I don't see it in the `man` page.

Comment: I know this option only from GNU tar. Your man page is probably incomplete. Try `info tar`.

Answer (score 0):

You can list multiple archive members in one command. That means you can do:

```
tar -tf some.tar.gz | grep '/index.php$' | xargs tar -xf some.tar.gz
```

Watch out for spaces in the paths though - maybe you need to replace newlines with null bytes and use `xargs -0`